# I keep getting "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am pretty new to coding in swift and need some help. I am making an app where random colored balloon nodes rise up on the screen and you pop them but if you miss a node of a certain color the game is supposed to end. However, I can't make the game end when the wrong color balloon leaves the screen. I am trying to compare the y position of the balloon with the y position of a node that is located at the top of the screen called "bounds" but I keep getting this error when I run my code `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`. Here's what I have Right now:

```
@objc func endGameWhenBalloonOut() {
    let Bounds = childNode(withName: "bounds")
    let redBalloon = childNode(withName: "RedBalloon")
    if childNode(withName: "redIndicator")?.zPosition == 5 &&   Double((redBalloon?.position.y)!) > Double((Bounds?.position.y)!)    {
         if let scene = GameOverSceneClass(fileNamed: "GameOver") {
              // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
              scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
              // Present the scene
              view!.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1))
              self.isPaused = true
              self.removeAllChildren()
              self.removeAllActions()
              self.scene?.removeFromParent()
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line this exception comes?

Comment: The error is coming here: Double((redBalloon?.position.y)!) > Double((Bounds?.position.y)!)

Comment: Don't use `!` here put a `guard` to check `nil` or `typecasting`.